# I added a terrain in Unity, but can't see it

Tags: unity, terrain

In Unity I added a terrain through **Create → 3D Object → Terrain.** It didn't show up and I can't see it. I tried to press <kbd>F</kbd> to focus on it, but I still don't see it. What am I doing wrong?

Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer. I should just have turned the coordinate system the way it is on the screenshot below: 
[image]

So my terrain was just hiding in the z-plane.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE! Don't forget to pick your answer after the 2 day wait period is over for self-answers. I hope you have a good time here among us :)

Comment: @JohnHamilton, it is pretty cosy! Thanks for the greetings! (B